# join a range of numbers to a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

i have a list of strings like this
`['apple', 'banana', 'nothing']`

and i'd like to convert it into something like this
`1-apple 2-banana 3-nothing`
i know that i can use `join` for static data but it's not helping
or maybe this:

```
range(10).join(...
```

but it won't work

Comment: The code you posted is not valid Python, so of course "it won't work".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
t = ['apple', 'banana', 'nothing']
res = " ".join([str(ind + 1) + '-' + item for ind, item in enumerate(t)])
print(res)
```

outputs:

```
1-apple 2-banana 3-nothing
```

Comment: That's a really inelegant way to `enumerate`…

Comment: Indeed it is :) I changed it to enumerate @deceze .

Comment: i don't want to content of join affects on range of numbers

Comment: @anonymouse Wat?

Comment: Since you really start enumerating with 1, you could express that more directly  with `enumerate(t, start=1)` or `enumerate(t, 1)`.